# Highcharts: add different colors to legend in one series histogram

Tags: javascript, highcharts, histogram, legend, series

I have sample code for question here: http://jsfiddle.net/pzamora/ztxPr/1/

I have different colors in my series, however I need them to appear in the legend

```
series: [{ name: 'V Genes',
        data: 
        [
            { 
                count: 18320.0, 
                y: 0.92, 
                color: '#3D96AE' 
            }, 
            { 
                count: 1337.0, 
                y: 0.17, 
                color: '#3D96AE' 
            }, 
            { 
                count: 33970.0, 
                y: 1.71, 
                color: '#4572A7' 
            }, 
            { 
                count: 1221.0, 
                y: 1.06, 
                color: '#3D96AE' 
            }, 
            { 
                count: 22073.0, 
                y: 1.11, 
                color: '#4572A7' 
            }, 
            { 
                count: 8331.0, 
                y: 0.42, 
                color: '#3D96AE' 
            }, 
            { 
                count: 64974.0, 
                y: 3.27, 
                color: '#4572A7' 
            },
            { 
                count: 9532.0, 
                y: 0.48, 
                color: '#3D96AE' 
            }, 
            { 
                count: 18106.0, 
                y: 0.91, 
                color: '#4572A7' 
            }
        ]
    }]
```

..I matched x values with the category position but I am not getting all my data displayed on the chart

@jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pzamora/phrP7/4/

Comment: The more I look at this the more confused I am. What exactly should the chart look like? The 'TRBxxxx' stuff does not seem to be like something you can split. For example if you had TRBV10-1 and TRBV10-1 (VB) I could sort of see where you are going. Is there any commonality between the VB and non-VB items? If not, why are you charting them together? If so, make two series and then use the tooltip to show VB and non-VB with legend colors to differentiate the 2 points.

Comment: I am expecting to get this http://uploadingit.com/file/view/d120kn4vwyu3b1bz/one_series.jpg

Comment: @pzamora Take a loot my updated answer, I was about the send my answer to the other question you asked when you deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Split data into two series
2. Add `color` for the legend in each series
3. Add `x` parameter to each value so they don't overlap

   ```
   series: [{ name: 'X Genes', color: '#3D96AE',
       data:
       [ 
           {
               count: 18320.0,
               y: 0.92,
               color: '#3D96AE',
               x: 0
           },
           {
               count: 1337.0,
               y: 0.17,
               color: '#3D96AE',
               x: 1
           },
           {
               count: 1221.0,
               y: 1.06,
               color: '#3D96AE',
               x: 3
           },
           {
               count: 8331.0,
               y: 0.42,
               color: '#3D96AE',
               x: 5
           },
           {
               count: 9532.0,
               y: 0.48,
               color: '#3D96AE',
               x: 7
           }
       ]
   },
   { name: 'V Genes', color: '#4572A7',
       data:
       [
           {
               count: 33970.0,
               y: 1.71,
               color: '#4572A7',
               x: 2
           },
           {
               count: 22073.0,
               y: 1.11,
               color: '#4572A7',
               x: 4
           },
           {
               count: 64974.0,
               y: 3.27,
               color: '#4572A7',
               x: 6
           },
           {
               count: 18106.0,
               y: 0.91,
               color: '#4572A7',
               x: 8
           }
       ]
   }]
   ```
4. Add `stacking: 'normal` to the `plotOptions` so that the values are in the middle of each column.

   ```
   plotOptions: {
           column: {
               cursor: 'pointer',
               stacking: 'normal'
           }
   },
   ```

Comment: I am happy with the colors, however I am still not getting them in the legend. I may want to split the data in two series, and fill the missing data with empty values to match the categories.

Comment: I thought you wanted to color each point's legend. I have updated the answer to reflect the graph you posted, is this what you need?

Comment: The `x` position tells you the order in which the columns will appear, i.e. `x: 0` will be the first, `x: 1` the second and so forth . As you have two series, you could have 2 columns with the same `x` and they would be shown together.

Comment: Thank you @sharif, link commented for now, will see if I can recover the code.

Answer (score 1):

For each legend element you have to create a serie.
So if you want two elements you have to create 2 series.
Then you have to set the `x` value for each point, to make the column stack on the categorie.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dwSh/)

So, if I have the following categorie:

```
['first', 'second', 'third']
```

My series have to have the following data:
serie1: `[{count: 400, y: 10, x: 1}]`
serie2: `[{count: 300, y: 5, x: 0}, {count: 500, y: 15, x: 2}]`

This case serie 1 appears on `second` and serie 2 on `first` and `third`.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dwSh/1/)

*Reference*

- [Serie data](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data)

**Update**:

Updated because she's an issue with the categories.
It happens because the `x` value have to be an `integer` and not a `string`.

```
{
    y: 40,
    x: 2,
    count: 300
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/phrP7/6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
series: [{ name: 'X Genes', color: '#3D96AE',
        data:
        [
            {
                count: 18320.0,
                y: 0.92,
                x: 0
            },
            {
                count: 1337.0,
                y: 0.17,
                x: 1
            },
            {
                count: 1221.0,
                y: 1.06,
                x: 3
            },
            {
                count: 8331.0,
                y: 0.42,
                x: 5
            },
            {
                count: 9532.0,
                y: 0.48,
                x: 7
            }
        ]
    },
    { name: 'V Genes', color: '#4572A7',
        data:
        [
            {
                count: 33970.0,
                y: 1.71,
                x: 2
            },
            {
                count: 22073.0,
                y: 1.11,
                x: 4
            },
            {
                count: 64974.0,
                y: 3.27,
                x: 6
            },
            {
                count: 18106.0,
                y: 0.91,
                x: 8
            }
        ]
    }]
```

You do not need to specify color attribute for each point if you specify it for series.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/ztxPr/16/)

Answer (score 0):

A series in the legend can only have one color while each point in a series can over-ride this color (as you have done in your code). If you want more data in your legend you could break up your single series into multiple with the codes you want. It is not entire clear what your expected outcome is for this question.

Comment: here the code with 2 series http://jsfiddle.net/pzamora/phrP7/1/          The problem is that my x Axis are different, the values from each series do not match the xAxis

Comment: categories: 
     ['TRBV10-1', 'TRBV11-1', 'TRBV11-3',  'TRBV10-3 (Vb 12)', 'TRBV11-2 (Vb 21.3)', 'TRBV12-3 (Vb 8)']

I have two kind of xAxis values, the ones with parenthesis, and the other ones, just want to make a difference, if i use two series the values in xAxis will never match in each serie

Comment: thats why my reason to use one series, all x values are different just want to point out that some of them have special description

Comment: K, one chart has 9 categories and the other has 6? Is what you want is to have both series on the same xAxis?

Comment: this is exactly what I need to achieve http://uploadingit.com/file/view/d120kn4vwyu3b1bz/one_series.jpg